# How object has anonymous function in Node.js

Tags: node.js, function, object, anonymous-function

in Node.js, process.hrtime is Object like that

`hrtime: { [Function: hrtime] bigint: [Function] },` (in pcoress object)

hrtime can be executed by `process.hrtime()` and has key `bigint` as a function that executed by `process.hrtime.bigint()`.

i wonder how it possible `hrtime` is a function and object at the same time.

i tried to include anonymous function in object, but failed.

how can i make it?

```
process {
  title: 'node',
  version: 'v10.16.3',
...
  hrtime: { [Function: hrtime] bigint: [Function] },
...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign properties on functions like you can onto any object.

```
function x() {
  console.log("You have successfully called x()!");
}

function y() {
  console.log("Hello, this is y()!");
}

x.y = y;

x();
x.y();
```

prints out

```
You have successfully called x()!
Hello, this is y()!
```

Comment: thank you! 
Not "anonymous function in object" but "property of function" !